# How can i transpose the data frame of specific column values?

Tags: r

I have data frame like below.

```
Country <- c("US","CA","UK","FR","US","CA","UK","FR","US","CA","UK","FR")

Month <- c(201901,201901,201901,201901,201902,201902,201902,201902,201903,201903,201903,201903)

HomeSales <- c(10,50,60,75,35,25,46,70,50,48,95,60)

CarSales <- c(10,50,60,75,35,25,46,70,50,48,95,60)

TransposeData <- data.frame(Country,Month,HomeSales,CarSales)
```

need to transpose same as below.

[image]

My products are always dynamic so i need to build the code to handle future products.
Kindly help me to build the logic for my data set. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You want to `gather` carsales and homesales and change the names to car and home?Like this `TransposeData %>% 
  gather(key,val,3:4)`? Where are you getting the dynamic data?

Comment: Need to transpose Car and Home sales under one sales column by displaying Car & home under new product column.

Comment: This I think completes "my" code above to get your desired result(it does not account for future changes, can rename columns ie key to product, val to sales): `mutate(key=case_when(key=="HomeSales" ~ "Home",
            TRUE ~ "Car"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot_longer` to convert from wide to long form and then `arrange` to sort it (if sorting is desired).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

TransposeData %>%
  pivot_longer(3:4, names_to = "Product", values_to = "Sales") %>% 
  arrange(Product, Country, Month)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 4
   Country  Month Product  Sales
   <fct>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 CA      201901 CarSales    50
 2 CA      201902 CarSales    25
 3 CA      201903 CarSales    48
 4 FR      201901 CarSales    75
 5 FR      201902 CarSales    70
 6 FR      201903 CarSales    60
 7 UK      201901 CarSales    60
 8 UK      201902 CarSales    46
 9 UK      201903 CarSales    95
10 US      201901 CarSales    10
# ... with 14 more rows
```